# How can I perform a phone call with the new Skype for Linux Alpha?

Tags: skype

I cannot find the option to perform a phone call in the new [Skype for Linux Alpha](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/skype-linux-alpha).

Has anyone found the option?

In the old client it looked as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature currently does not exist. Looking at the `Available and upcoming features` list on the [information page](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34656/more-information-about-skype-for-linux-alpha), you can see that Alpha currently does not support PSTN calling, among other things:

[image]

([higher quality image for no real reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM5AG.png))

The website also has this:

> **Is Skype calling for landlines and mobiles supported?**
>   No, currently this feature is not supported on Skype for Linux Alpha. But stay tuned!

You'll just have to wait for them to add it.